# xcode gdb pauses on ipad device

Tags: ipad

I'm try to create some images and store it inside the Documents folder. When I run it on the simulator it is fine. However when I run it through the ipad device, the gdb just pauses at a certain point and doesn't give me much information to work with. I used the analyser to check what items to release to check memory leaks. Im running 4.3 SDK.

I'm not sure what the actual issue is. Sometimes looping through 100 images and storing them is ok but then after a while it just pauses. Where can I look further for debug or clues on how to fix this. I have provided some code.

```
for(int i = 0; i < totalpages; i++)
{
    NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%d.jpg", 
        imageFullPathFolder, i+1];

    if(![manager fileExistsAtPath:imagePath])
    {
        NSString *urlParams = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SOMEURL", 
            fileSourceId, i+1];
        NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlParams];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData 
            dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl]];
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
        [manager createFileAtPath:imagePath contents:imageData 
            attributes:nil];

        [imageData release];
    }   
}
```

Comment: Does `*urlParams` and all those inner-loop variables need the `*`? I'm curious: does that mean that all those `totalpages` number of strings, urls, and images, remain in memory when the loop ends? (Or, what prevents those from being leaked?)

Comment: I need them as a string so correct me if im wrong I need to use *? I believe all those variables do. When I try to do a release on those strings and images, the analyzer just says that im not the caller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to release the image data returned by UIImageJPEGRepresentation (you don't own it; you're over-releasing it).

Comment: i removed the released but while the files are copying over to the ipad device it still pauses. when loops do all the urlparams, imageurl, image, imagedata remain in memory? so if the loop is 1000 iterations, how can you ensure that only one instance of each is used, then released for each iteration.

Comment: @fes: if you want to keep your memory usage in check, you can use an NSAutoreleasePool inside the loop: `NSAutoreleasePool *p = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; /* ...do work... */ [p release];`

Comment: That's what I ended up doing in the for loop. To be honest I do not know why this works but for the time being its doing the job.

Comment: @fes: Normally when you get objects from methods like `imageWithData:`, `URLWithString:`, etc., they are autoreleased, which means you don't have to manually release them later, they will be released automatically. However this only happens at the end of the run loop, so if you're creating a lot of autoreleased objects you can use your own NSAutoreleasePool to release them sooner and use less memory.

Comment: I see, I think that was the issue. The memory was being built up and since it doesn't get auto-released until the very end it just decided to stop. While this wasn't an issue on the imac running the simulator but was an issue on the ipad device itself. The NSAutoReleasePool now makes sense in this case. Cheers.